# Ajax in Opencart not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, opencart

I am customising the product page in OC (image attached below) and looks good but the ajax for the cart isn't working, I can't add the product to the cart, I just get the generic error that the "option" isn't selected.

Code:

```
<div class="widget">
 <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
 <?php if ($option['type'] == 'radio') { ?>
  <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
   <div class="title">
    <h2><?php echo $option['name']; ?>:</h2>
   </div>
   <table >
    <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <label>
        <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['option_value_id']; ?>" />
        <span style="width:40%;"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?></span>
        <?php if($option_value['quantity'] == 0) { ?>
         <span style="width:20%;">Out of stock</span>
        <?php } else { ?>
         <span style="width:20%;"><?php echo $option_value['quantity']; ?> remaining</span>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
         <span style="width:10%;"><?php echo $option_value['prefix']; ?> <?php echo $option_value['price']; ?></span> 
        <?php } else { ?> 
         <span style="width:10%;"><?php echo $option_value['prefix']; ?> <?php echo $special; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
       </label>
      </td>
     </tr>
    <?php } ?>
   </table>
  </div>
 <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
 <div class="cart">
    <?php echo $text_qty; ?>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" id="button-cart" class="button" />
    <?php if ($minimum > 1) { ?>
     <div class="minimum">
      <?php echo $text_minimum; ?>
     </div>
    <?php } ?>
   </div>
```

Ajax Code for the above is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#notification').hide();
$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
data: $('input[type=\'text\'], input[type=\'hidden\'], input[type=radio]:checked'),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
                }
            }
        } 

        if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').show();
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
        }   
     }
       });
         });
         //--></script>
```

Image:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26243182/oc-options.png

If I run the following jQuery script it tells me the contents of the radio button

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  alert($(this).val());
}
```

});

I am probably missing something dead simple but it's driving me mental :)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you check the ajax response in console?

Comment: nothing in Firebug console

Comment: anyone able to help? It's driving me insane as it's going to be something simple but I can't work it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

huh, the error you get is if ajax simply fails to read the option you specified meaning that a value is not being read, as such you should change `input[type=radio]` to `input[type=]\'radio\']` also if this fails too try

```
'input[name=\'option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]\']:checked'
```

i think this one of these will be the right one for you or at least guide you, this is for the ajax code ofc.

Comment: Didn't solve it, found the error in the end Fixed it by going back to basics and rewriting the functions from the default theme and it fixed it, looks like there was an error in the radio code, not sure what but it works so I can now relax :)

Comment: `input[type=\'radio\']` nor `input[type="radio"]` are not needed at all and simply using `input[type=radio]` will work every time with jQuery unless You need to do something like `input[data-title="this is some edgecase that should not happen"]`...